# Number guessing game. Number of Guesses made.

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a number game where the user enters a number from 1-100, and it the script will attempt to guess in 10 guesses the user's input. If within 10 guesses it guesses the right number it wins, otherwise the user wins. So far I got it work properly, except I'm having issues trying to have it display the number of guesses made at the end of the game. So for example, if 10 guesses were made than it should show "Number of guesses made: 10" or Number of guesses made: 5" (if guessed in 5).

```js
window.guessNum = function () {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "";
    var guesses = 10;
    var input = parseInt(document.getElementById("numberGuess").value);
    do {
        var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
         
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "I'll guess " + randomNum + " <br />";
        if (input == randomNum) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "Our numbers match. I win!! :)<br /><br />";
        guesses = 0;
       }
       if (input < randomNum) {
       document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "Your input is less than the number I'm thinking about. <br /><br />";
       } else if (input > randomNum) {
       document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "Your input is greater than the number I'm thinking about.<br /><br />";
       }
       guesses = guesses - 1;
       }
       while (guesses > 0);
       if (input != randomNum) {
       document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "I can't figure it out. I guess you win!<br /><br />";
       }
       document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "Number of guesses: " +guesses+ " <br />";
    }
```

```html
<h1>Number Game</h1>
<div id="mainCont">
  <p>Number:
    <input type="text" id="numberGuess">
    <input type="button" onclick="guessNum();" value="Guess">
  </p>
  <div id="guess"></div>
  <div id="result"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please edit your previous question for improvement instead of re-posting it.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the amount of guesses you have left not the amount of guesses made.

Answer (score 0):

The counter you are printing is the one where you count down the amount of guess you have left. Instead of trying to print that for the amount of guesses made add another counter where you increment the value for each `do` repeat and then print this when you are done.

Added `guessesMade` in three places below:

```
window.guessNum = function () {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "";
    var guesses = 10;

    var guessesMade = 0;

    var input = parseInt(document.getElementById("numberGuess").value);

    do {
        guessesMade++;

        var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;

        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "I'll guess " + randomNum + " <br />";
        if (input == randomNum) {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "Our numbers match. I win!! :)<br /><br />";
            guesses = 0;
        }

        if (input < randomNum) {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "Your input is less than the number I'm thinking about. <br /><br />";
        } else if (input > randomNum) {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "Your input is greater than the number I'm thinking about.<br /><br />";
        }

        guesses = guesses - 1;
    }
    while (guesses > 0);

    if (input != randomNum) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "I can't figure it out. I guess you win!<br /><br />";
    }

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "Number of guesses: " +guessesMade+ " <br />";
}
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dpbkv6pp/

Comment: thank you all! Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can `break` from while `loop` when the match happens like this:

```js
window.guessNum = function () {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "";
    var guesses = 10;
    var input = parseInt(document.getElementById("numberGuess").value);
    do {
        guesses = guesses - 1;
        var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
         
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "I'll guess " + randomNum + " <br />";
        if (input == randomNum) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "Our numbers match. I win!! :)<br /><br />";
        break;
       }
       if (input < randomNum) {
       document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "Your input is less than the number I'm thinking about. <br /><br />";
       } else if (input > randomNum) {
       document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "Your input is greater than the number I'm thinking about.<br /><br />";
       }

       }
       while (guesses > 0);
       if (input != randomNum) {
       document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "I can't figure it out. I guess you win!<br /><br />";
       }
       document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "Number of guesses: " +(10-guesses)+ " <br />";
    }
```

```html
<h1>Number Game</h1>
<div id="mainCont">
  <p>Number:
    <input type="text" id="numberGuess">
    <input type="button" onclick="guessNum();" value="Guess">
  </p>
  <div id="guess"></div>
  <div id="result"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you wish to change the maximum amount of guesses you have to remember to change the print as well or you will end up printing 10 guesses either way (if you change to a higher value than 10).

Comment: Breaking is however a good suggestion! :]